# Difference in cli "find" between debian and macOS

Tags: macos, debian, file-management, zsh, find

I just moved fro mDebian to macOS after my laptop crashed. Luckily I was abele to salvage my .zshrc with my aliases, however, m two aliases that use "find" don't seem to work in macOS and I am not quite sure what the difference is.

The first command is supposed to move all files fro msubdirectories to the current directory and it worked flawlessly on debian:

```
alias mup='find -type f -exec mv {} . \;'
```

On macOS however I get a "find: illegal option -- t"

Similarly, to change the file ending from JPG to jpg I used

```
alias jprn="find -name '*.JPG' -exec rename "s/.JPG/.jpg/g" \{\} \;"
```

which results in another "find: illegal option -- n"

Unfortunately, the error is rather mysterious, so I don't even know where to start looking for a resolution, as all the handles seem to be correct based on man.

Any info or pointer would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

for `mup`, `find` needs a `path` argument:

`alias mup='find . -type f -exec mv {} . \;'`

for `jprn`, `find` needs a `path` argument. Also, there's no `rename` command in macOS (you can install it with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) though). This is the best I could come up with at the moment:

`alias jprn='find . -name "*.JPG" -print | while read -r f; do mv "$f" "${f/%JPG/jpg}"; done'`

`${f/%JPG/jpg}` substitutes `$f` ending in `JPG` with `jpg`, see the last part of section "Parameter Expansion" in `man zshexpn`.

Comment: I'd recommend using `... -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' f; do ...` to avoid trouble when filenames contain spaces and other funny characters (which are common on macOS). See [BashFAQ #20: How can I find and safely handle file names containing newlines, spaces or both?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020)